# In Haskell, is there some way to forcefully coerce a polymorphic call?

Tags: haskell, types

I have a list of values (or functions) of any type. I have another list of functions of any type. The user at runtime will choose one from the first list, and another from the second list. I have a mechanism to ensure that the two items are type compatible (value or output from first is compatible with input of second).

I need some way to call the function with the value (or compose the functions). If the second function has concrete types, unsafeCoerce works fine. But if it's of the form:

```
polyFunc :: MyTypeclass a => a -> IO ()
polyFunc x = print . show . typeclassFunc x
```

Then unsafeCoerce doesn't work since it can't resolve to a concrete type.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Here's an example of what the lists might look like. However... I'm not limited to this, if there is some other way to represent these that will solve the problem, I would like to know. A critical thing to consider is that: the list can change at runtime so I do not know at compile time all the possible types that might be involved.

```
data Wrapper = forall a. Wrapper a
firstList :: [Wrapper]
firstList = [Wrapper "blue", Wrapper 5, Wrapper valueOfMyTypeclass]
data OtherWrapper = forall a. Wrapper (a -> IO ())
secondList :: [OtherWrapper]
secondList = [OtherWrapper print, OtherWrapper polyFunc]
```

Note: As for why I want to do such a crazy thing:
I'm generating code and typechecking it with hint. But that happens at runtime. The problem is that hint is slow at actually executing things and high performance for this is critical. Also, at least in certain cases, I do not want to generate code and run it through ghc at runtime (though we have done some of that, too). So... I'm trying to find somewhere in the middle: dynamically hook things together without having to generate code and compile, but run it at compiled speed instead of interpreted.

Comment: Look at Data.Dynamic and Data.Typeable - those can do what you need.

Comment: For the most part yes, they're better than `unsafeCoerce`, but they don't answer the polymorphic part of this question.

Comment: Maybe you could add some more code to give us a chance to find a way to solve that differently.

Comment: I deliberately did not include more code because I was concerned people would limit their considerations to my code. I asked a question recently and got the result "your approach won't work", so I'm trying to figure out if there is an approach that will. But I just added some code to try to illustrate at least one way the lists might be represented.

Comment: It's an obvious question but, if you are generating code - why are you generating code that might fail type checking?

Comment: @stephen to find out which combinations of items are compatible. Try all the combinations, and whatever type checks, those are the allowed combinations to allow the user to choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: Okay, so now that I see what's going on a bit more, here's a very general approach -- don't use polymorphic functions directly at all! Instead, use functions of type `Dynamic -> IO ()`! Then, they can use "typecase"-style dispatch directly to choose which monomorphic function to invoke -- i.e. just switching on the TypeRep. You *do* have to encode this dispatch directly for each polymorphic function you're wrapping. However, you can automate this with some template Haskell if it becomes enough of a hassle.

Essentially, rather than overloading Haskell's polymorphism, just as `Dynamic` *embeds* an dynamically typed language in a statically typed language, you now extend that to *embed* dynamic polymorphism in a statically typed language.

--

Old answer: More code would be helpful. But, as far as I can tell, this is the read/show problem. I.e. You have a function that produces a polymorphic result, and a function that takes a polymorphic input. The issue is that *you* need to pick what the intermediate value is, such that it satisfies both constraints. If you have a mechanism to do so, then the usual tricks will work, making sure you satisfy that open question which the compiler can't know the answer to.

Comment: I don't think this is a read/show situation because there is a value created with a concrete type (from the first list I mention) at least internally. But I do not know at compile time what that concrete type is since it depends on which thing the user chooses from the list. I only know at runtime that if I generated code composing the two selected functions (because I restrict the user to only choosing a compatible pair), they would compile and run fine.

Comment: @taotree: Isn't that pretty much the definition of an existential type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps the code I just added would help explain?

Comment: @taotree You say, "...if I generated code composing the two selected functions, they would compile and run fine.". Have you proved this? What is preventing you from writing down this proof in a form the compiler can understand -- that is, as code that typechecks? This smells a lot like an X/Y problem.

Comment: @Daniel: I added a note at the bottom of the question answering why. Yes, I have proved it, but it's done at runtime, so that's why I can't provide it to the compiler.

Comment: @sclv the new edit looks interesting. Could you or someone perhaps provide a code example of how to do that dispatch? That would mean that the functions in the second list would have to know in advance all the concrete types they are willing to handle, right? Unlike type classes, someone just can't add an instance somewhere and suddenly it works for another type? In other words, since it's the openness of typeclasses that is making it such that the compiler won't do what I want, we'd be simulating a closed typeclass approach so it can?

Comment: And it's better than switching over a union type because the incoming values (first list) don't need to know about the union type. It might throw a wrench in the works for my type checking, though, since now there is nothing in the function signature that indicates what types it accepts. But I might be able to get around that with some clever template haskell. Some TH that will auto convert polyFunc as defined into a Dynamic-TypeRep switch dispatcher. Then use polyFunc for typechecking and the generated thing for execution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your question. But since you have value and function which have compatible types you could combine them into single value. Then compiler could prove that types do match.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Vault = forall a . Vault (a -> IO ()) a

runVault :: Vault -> IO ()
runVault (Vault f x) = f xrun
```

Comment: That does not resolve the core issue which is the use of type classes.